@SortNatural and @SortComparator in Hibernate
I am not able to understand the working of @SortNatural and @SortComparator.
Lets take @SortNatural first.
@ElementCollection
@SortNatural
SortedSet<String> images = new TreeSet<>();

What is the use of @SortNatural in the above code, as when we add the elements in the Set, the SortedSet is going to perform the sorting and similarily when loading to the sorted set from the DB by Hibernate, the sorting will happen, so it seems this @SortNatural is redundant here?? Please clarify.
Also can we use @SortNatural on a Set which has HashSet implementation like below:-
@ElementCollection
@SortNatural
Set<String> images = new HashSet<>();

Now coming to @SortComparator, so if we specify a class inside the @SortComparator will the SortedSet use the same class to order its elements or will it use its default implementation of Comparable to sort the value??
@ElementCollection
@SortComparator(ReverseString.class)
SortedSet<String> names = new TreeSet<>();

Like in the above code will SortedSet use ReverseString.class or its own internal implementation.
Will @SortComparator store the value in the same order in the DB??
Kindly help in clarifying the working of these two annotations as based on Docs its not clear what is their purpose?
Anyone please help here.

https://thorben-janssen.com/ordering-vs-sorting-hibernate-use/

Hi I went through the above link, but it still does not answer my above question.
